# How to stop & exit jenkins from Kubernetes cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have installed Jenkins through Helm with below commands.

```
$ chart=jenkinsci/jenkins
$ helm install jenkins -n jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml $chart
```

Now how do i stop & exit Jenkins completely from my kubernetes cluster?

```
# kubectl delete pod jenkins-0 -n jenkins
pod "jenkins-0" deleted
```

After delete pod command, still it creates new pod.

```
# kubectl get pods -n jenkins
NAME        READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-0   0/2     Init:0/1   0          6s
```

Comment: `# helm uninstall jenkins -n jenkins` helped me to remove it.

Comment: Hi user4948798!  Have you solved your issues using this command?

Comment: Hello Ivan, Yes able to remove the jenkins along with its deployment.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as the **answer** so it will be visible to the community?

Comment: Yes. Sure. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have Jenkins installed through `helm`. So I have removed the pod and complete deployment inside my namespace using `# helm uninstall jenkins -n jenkins`.